# Maven build created for Selenium automation failing in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have created Selenium automation project using Maven and trying to build using Jenkins but encountering the below issue

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ BigBasket ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.147 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-13T02:42:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/180M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project BigBasket: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test/target/classes/application.yml (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test/pom.xml to com.bigbasket.framework/BigBasket/1.0-SNAPSHOT/BigBasket-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[WARNING] Couldn't clean up oid=3 from null
hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: channel is already closed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:578)
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.` and then add the results to your initial question.

Comment: It was an access issue and I fixed it myself.